# Convert $\cos t$ to a function of $t-\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to take the Lapace tranformation of this function. I looked it up in the solutionsheet but I don't understand how they convert $u(t-\pi)\cos t$ to $-u(t-\pi)\cos(t-\pi)$.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that [cost](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cost) is not what you probably mean?

Comment: Yes. I dont understand how they get to the second line i the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).
$$- \cos t = \cos (\pi - t) = \cos (t - \pi)$$
The above wikipedia page has a lot of pretty useful trigonometric identities as well you may require in future.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(t-\pi)=-\cos(t)$ by the [trigonometric addition formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html).

$$\cos(t-\pi) = \cos t \cos(-\pi) - \sin t\sin(-\pi) = \cos t\cdot (-1) - \sin t\cdot 0 = -\cos t $$

Comment: @mr_e_man Fixed, thanks!